# Screw in the bottom plate of Cuisinart convection CBK 200 bread maker-do not recognize

Tags: repair

I’m trying to remove the bottom plate of my bread maker. The paddles in the bread bucket are not turning easily. I read that you can remove the bottom plate and check the belts. Two of the screws are Philip heads and two are not anything I recognize. Any help is appreciated.  [image]

Comment: They are odd.  If needle nose or similar tool will not turn those tabs, they might need to be wiggled out first(locking tabs).  I bet Cuisinart has a special, not for sale tool for them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't really a Home Improvement question...

Comment: If its the paddle - it *might* be a bearing in the bread pan - does it turn smoothly on its own? If not, there's replacement kits online - and you wouldn't need to tear your breakmaker apart.

Comment: Stop by your local hardware store and pick up a set of ~100 security bits for ~$20 or so. Somewhere in that set should be a couple of different sized bits with two little prongs that'll turn those.

Comment: @crip, no, they're a really common head when the manufacturer doesn't want just anyone opening it up, but isn't too bothered.  The same screwdriver bit as a snake-eyes head will do, found in any generic security bit set

Answer (score 5):

That's a high security screw head.  They don't want you in there. :)

You can get a kit of specialty bits for such screws, or you can hacksaw a slot in an open blade screwdriver.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Didn’t think about hacking an existing screw driver. Inventive.